# Is there a unique ID for objects clicked within target?

Tags: javascript, html, target

With the following code, as you can see with each oval created, the name always remains the same.
So no matter which oval I click, I get the same name. Is there some kind of unique ID buried in the target attribute?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<input type="button" onClick="doit()" value="Do it">

<script>
function doit() {
    drawOval(160,80,50);
    myOval = document.getElementById("newdiv");
} 

function drawOval(width, height, radius) {
    if (document.createElement) {

       newdiv=document.createElement("div");
       newdiv.style.width = width+"px";
       newdiv.style.height = height+"px";
       newdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
       newdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
       newdiv.style.borderRadius = radius+"%"

       newdiv.id = 'newdiv';// + i;
       document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}

document.onclick = function(f){
    alert(f.target.id)
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, with `newdiv.id = 'newdiv';` your id will be the same

Comment: I don't see how anything can work in an html document without a **body**

Comment: @MisterJojo The body is [optional](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-body-element). Also see [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags): _"A body element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the body element is not ASCII whitespace or a comment, except if the first thing inside the body element is a meta, link, script, style, or template element."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<input type="button" onClick="doit()" value="Do it">

<script>
    var id = 1;
function doit() {
    drawOval(160,80,50);
    myOval = document.getElementById("newdiv");
} 

function drawOval(width, height, radius) {
    if (document.createElement) {

       newdiv=document.createElement("div");
       newdiv.style.width = width+"px";
       newdiv.style.height = height+"px";
       newdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
       newdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
       newdiv.style.borderRadius = radius+"%"

       newdiv.id = 'newdiv' + id;// + i;
        id++;
       document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}

document.onclick = function(f){
    alert(f.target.id)
}
</script>

</html>
```